# Why is Shapely and contains_point not detecting point being on land?

Tags: point-in-polygon, shapely

I'm using the world shapefile that can be found at https://trac.openstreetmap.org/browser/applications/editors/merkaartor-branches/merkaartor-0.14-fixes/share/world_shp/world_adm0.shp?rev=17052.

I've plotted the point (150.625, -26.7396) (longitude, latitude) using QGIS and clearly it is on land.

Here's my code:

```
import pysal as ps # asShape, contains_point;
import shapely.geometry # asShape, buffer

WORLD_FILE = 'world_adm0.shp'
BUFF = 0.005

polygons = ps.open(WORLD_FILE)

found = False

for polygon in polygons:
    sh_poly = shapely.geometry.asShape(polygon)
    sh_buff_poly = sh_poly.buffer(BUFF)
    buff_poly = ps.cg.asShape(sh_buff_poly)

    if buff_poly.contains_point((150.625, -26.7396)):
        found = True
        break

if found:
    print("on land")
else:
    print("in sea")
```

Why do I get "in sea"?

Comment: In my tests, it returns "in sea" with your code, and it returns "on land" if we skip the buffering step. Not sure why though, perhaps a bug. How did you install shapely, and which version of shapely and pysal do you have?

Comment: To install: module load python/2.7.6 then pip search pysal followed by pip -v install pySAL. Shapely is version 1.5.2 and 
PySAL is version 1.8.0.

Comment: You're mixing PySAL and Shapely methods. Choose one of the modules, stick with it, and you'll probably get better results.

Answer (score 5):

This is a previously unknown bug in PySAL. The issue is with the implementation of the contains_point method. The method does not properly account for multipart polygons. PySAL projects a ray from the point through the left side of the polygon and counts the intersections between the polygon's line segments and the ray. If 0 or an even number of intersections is found the point is not contained in the polygon. However, due to a bug, PySAL is including extra line segments connecting the parts of multiple polygons. The attached image shows how PySAL is seeing your buffered polygon...

[image: Demonstration of PySAL's Point in Polygon Bug]

If you count the intersections you'll notice there are 6, however if you ignore the obviously erroneous segements there is exactly 1 intersection.

I added an [issue](https://github.com/pysal/pysal/issues/603) for this on PySAL's github account and hopefully it will be fixed in the next release. Thanks for pointing it out! In the meantime, you can use pysal's get_polygon_point_intersect function (pysal.cg.get_polygon_point_intersect) which correctly deals with multipart polygons.